# How do I turn Google Play Books pages with Voice?

Tags: ebooks, voice-command, google-play-books

I use Google Play Books a lot, especially for tech books and programming etc. Is there any way I can turn pages of an app, specifically Google Play Books, using my voice?

Comment: On Jellybean, simply saying `next` `previous` `back` `forward` will have to work.

Comment: Are you saying this is how it should be or how it is now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Google Books has a voice interface, which is a shame.  I don't know of any book app which does, I'm afraid. [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp)  is a great ebook app which has auto page turning, based on time, but they are very active and are always adding features - it may be worth emailing them and asking if they will implement it?

Comment: That would be an interesting option. I wonder if Google Play Books is going to open up our books so other applications utilize them. Or have they already? If so then I would put effort into lobbying Moon+ Reader.

Comment: So, if there are any Android devs out there looking for a good idea for an app, this would be great! Simply left and right would be sufficient for 90% of users. I would hope Google is working on this but 3rd party is more realistic I think. I would probably pay 5 dollars for this functionality if it were available.